# What are the time periods of each salah?

Tags: salat

I have searched many times but haven't been able to get an answer to my question.

I know that Maghrib becomes qada when we can not see the sun rays anymore, but what about other salah times?

Till what time can I pray each salah if there is a delay and I am not able to read salah on the time of it's beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fajr** begins at subh saadiq, true dawn or the beginning of twilight, when the morning light appears across the full width of the sky  and ends at sunrise.

The time interval for offering the **Zuhr** starts after the sun passes its zenith and lasts until 20 min (approx) before the call for the Asr prayer is to be given.

The **Asr** prayer starts when the shadow of an object is the same length as the object itself (or, according to Hanafi school, twice its length) plus the shadow length at zuhr, and lasts till sunset. The recommended time to pray Asr is before the sun starts to turn orange.

The **Maghrib** prayer begins when the sun sets, and lasts until the red light has left the sky in the west.

The **Isha** prayer starts when the red light is gone from the western sky, and lasts until the rise of the "white light" (fajr sadiq) in the east.

**Source**: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salah_times)

Comment: Thankyou, this answers most of my question, however, it is for sure dependent on the colours of the sky, for example, what if clouds in the sky restrict my view upon the setting sun and I am unable to see what colour the sun or sky beholds at the time of Maghrib?

Comment: The above answer gives a general idea on the Salat timings. Please note that these timings are a range and not a specific moment or minute in time. Thus if we know generally when a specific salat time begins or ends, we can do ijtehad and determine the same during a cloudy day. Unless you plan to go hiking or live in a very remote place, it is very likely that you will access to internet or hear azan  from a nearby masjid giving you a fair idea. Alternately, I recommend you consult a nearby scholar in your masjid/area to determine timings for your location (esp if you live close to the poles).